# swift early function exit swift without guard

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, function

I'm looking for a way to exit a function without using guard. After extensive searching, I cannot find a way to exit a function and call the next at the same time when a button it pressed.
The button calls a repeat using a selector:

```
@IBAction func BottomLeft(sender: AnyObject) {
    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(NSTimeInterval(0.01), target: self, selector: "bottomLeftMovement", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

This is when the code button is pressed, and the ball will follow this movement:

```
func bottomLeftMovement() {
    Ballx = Ballx - 0.6125
    Bally = Bally + 1.2
    self.Ball.center.x = Ballx
    self.Ball.center.y = Bally
}
```

I am looking to make it so that when a different button is pressed, that this function will be exited and the corresponding one will be called.

I cannot hard program into the first function, as it is an interchangeable thing, as opposed to a function chain.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: In almost every programming language a function can be exit using `return`.

Comment: Yeah, that's not gonna work, because his code is starting a timer that repeatedly calls the other function. And to top it off, a new timer is created every time a tap is detected. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your code is doing is creating a new timer every time you tap on the button. This is not the correct way to do this. I'd recommend you do some research/reading on game development.
But basically, if you're gonna do things this way (which again, is not a good thing (tm)). You need to keep track of your timer in a property, and invalidate it (to stop it). Read about timers too (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/)

So, in short:
 - don't do this
 - if you must, track your timer in a property
 - invalidate() your timer and start a new one as required

Note: Track and invalidate the timer like this:
(note I'm doing this from memory, not tested, but something along the lines of...)

```
class someClass {
  var myTimer = NSTimer?

  func myFunction() {
     if let timer = myTimer {
         timer.invalidate()
     }

     timer = NSTimer(...
```

Comment: Thanks for this, am i correct in thinking that to call the invalidate function i simply put "invalidate()" between the timer on a button tap and the start of the timer, i.e.        @IBAction func BottomLeft(sender: AnyObject) {       invalidate()
        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(NSTimeInterval(0.01), target: self, selector: "bottomLeftMovement", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }